# Recovery kernel boots into root with no menu

Tags: 11.10, kernel, root, data-recovery

I've had this problem ever since the oneiric upgrade. Recovery kernel boots straight into root prompt, with no menu.

I also can't telinit 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the friendly-recovery package.

```
sudo apt-get install friendly-recovery
```

Comment: friendly-recovery is already the newest version

Comment: I am running a slightly older oneiric kernel, telinit takes me directly to the LightDM login screen. It should take me to a non-root prompt.